# How to get order store config variable in Admin

Tags: magento, config, store, payment

I created a module where it return via xml the payment details in Magento Admin order page.
It works very well with a single store config data.

But if I have diferents payment credentials for Store Id 1 and store Id 2 [p.e. for backoffice key 1111-1111-1111-1111 (store 1) and other 2222-2222-2222-2222 (store 2), I only can return the default values for admin view with this function...

```
$subent_id = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/multibancopayment/subentidade');
```

Does any one khow how i can get store specific data based in order store id?
Example: in admin order page details, if the order was made in store 1 I need 1111-1111-1111-1111, but if was made in store 2, I need 2222-2222-2222-2222. For now I'm just getting default values with the function above.

[image: MB payment]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try

```
$subent_id = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/multibancopayment/subentidade', $storeIdHere);
```

See /app/Mage.php

```
/**
 * Retrieve config value for store by path
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @param mixed $store
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function getStoreConfig($path, $store = null)
{
    return self::app()->getStore($store)->getConfig($path);
}
```

[Entire class here](http://freegento.com/doc/d8/dcb/class_mage.html#39fabcc2c75f6dcf35459ad632775c85)

Comment: Without seeing your code it hard to debug... did you try  `Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/multibancopayment/subentidade', $order->getStoreId());`

Comment: Oops, sorry was testing with wrong store id [manual introduction]. Thanks R.S.